# I am trying to execute my android code emulator initialization taking too long time but didn't show the device showing error in event log error

Tags: android

Can not run program "C:\Users\TCT003\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First of all check whether you installed all plugins correctly or not.
If you are installed plugins and all correctly and your not able to build projects that means something is blocking you adb.exe.

Most probably it will be your Antivirus or Firewall. Disable it and check.

2.This error can also appear because of Permissions issues. Right-click platform-tools folder in your Android SDK folder and in Security tab make sure "All" can Read and Execute. I've come across this problem sometimes after updating the Android SDK tools in Android Studio.

Comment: "C:\Users\TCT003\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" in my platform-tools folder not contain any folder like adb.exe...

Comment: you have to download the plugin for emulator